# customized backbutton working like real back button xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3

i am making a customized back button which works exactly as a real back button does. below is my code

```
UIButton *cusBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];
[cusBack setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cusBack addTarget:self action:@selector(clickBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.view addSubView:cusBack;
```

and here is my selector:

```
-(void)clickBack{
PrevPage *pPage = [[PrevPage alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pPage animated:YES];
[pPage release];
}
```

actually, it works but the direction it creates is from RIGHT to LEFT. but I want the page to move from LEFT to RIGHT since it goes back to the recent page

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same behavior as the back button you should try another approach:

```
-(void)clickBack{          //Your presenting view controller will always be the last view controller on the stack.                  
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-1] animated:YES];
}
```

Also, if you need to do some changes to the previous view controller, all you need to do is import it's header file and then you can use it's properties and public methods before popping the view controller.

```
#import "MyPreviousViewController.h"
...
-(void)clickBack{
[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-1].title = @"Change title for previous view controller";
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-1] animated:YES];
}
```

Currently, your back button doesn't work as the real back button does, because, instead of popping the last view controller off the stack(also releasing the objects), you actually keep pushing new view controllers on the stack. You might have some issues if this stack gets too big.